# ant emma BUILD FAILED

Tags: android, testing, ant, code-coverage, emma

I try to run android unit test with code coverage. I'm using the Android example NotePad.

These are the commands I used:

```
cd <main project folder>
android update project --path .
android update test-project -m <full path to main project> -p <full path to main project>\tests
cd ./tests
ant emma debug install test
```

the tests runs successfully. But in the end emma can't generate the report html File.

Here you get the commandline output of ant emma debug install test

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\build.xml

emma:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: NotesListTest
  [gettype] Project Type: Test Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for NotesListTest...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for NotesListTest...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building tested project at C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad with 'instrument'...

-set-mode-check:

-set-instrumented-mode:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: NotesList
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for NotesList...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for NotesList...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'instrument'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\classes
     [echo] Instrumenting classes from C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin/classes...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\classes
      [dex] input: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\emma_device.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed emma_device-e05f8994020e22cd9d939f07950bd18a.jar <- C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\emma_device.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (17 defs/29,2KiB) with dex B (297 defs/326,8KiB). Result is 314 defs/427,2KiB. Took 0,2s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
[apkbuilder] Creating NotesList-instrumented-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\NotesList-instrumented.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop

instrument:
 [zipalign] Run cancelled: no changes to input file C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\NotesList-instrumented-unaligned.apk
     [echo] Instrumented Package: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\NotesList-instrumented.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\build.prop
[testedprojectclasspath] Resolved classpath:
[testedprojectclasspath] C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\classes

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\classes
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\classes.dex...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
[apkbuilder] Creating NotesListTest-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\NotesListTest-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

install:
     [echo] Installing C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\NotesListTest-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
     [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/NotesListTest-debug.apk
     [exec] Success
     [exec] 494 KB/s (8101 bytes in 0.016s)

-set-mode-check:

-set-instrumented-mode:

install:
     [echo] Installing C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\bin\NotesList-instrumented.apk onto default emulator or device...
     [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/NotesList-instrumented.apk
     [exec] Success
     [exec] 629 KB/s (211536 bytes in 0.328s)

installi:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: NotesListTest
  [gettype] Project Type: Test Application

-test-project-check:

test:
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] No Libraries
     [echo] Running tests...
     [echo] Running tests ...
     [exec] 
     [exec] com.example.android.notepad.NotePadActivityTest:.
     [exec] com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProviderTest:..........
     [exec] Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=...........
     [exec] Time: 2.338
     [exec] 
     [exec] OK (11 tests)
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generated code coverage data to /data/data/com.example.android.notepad/coverage.ec
     [echo] Setting permission to download the coverage file...
     [exec] run-as: Package 'com.example.android.notepad' is unknown
     [echo] Downloading coverage file into project directory...
     [exec] failed to copy '/data/data/com.example.android.notepad/coverage.ec' to 'C:\Users\Benedikt\workspace_android\NotePad\tests\bin\coverage.ec': Permission denied
     [echo] Extracting coverage report...

BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1313: [EMMA v2.0.5312] report: no valid input data files have been specified

Total time...
```

I would like to post the C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml but the file is to long. But i guess it is always the same...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command ant emma debug install test is only successfull on a rooted device or on an emulator (otherwise permission denied).

Useful hints:

- If you're using SDK 13 or older you've to use *ant coverage* instead of *ant emma debug install test*
- One of the last output lines show you where the report file has been saved
- If you use Windows you have to add the Path of the android.bat (normally /tools) and the path of the ant.bat (depending where you installed Ant; If you use Eclipse with ADT it is normally there: /plugins/org.apache.ant.../bin) to the PATH Variable (you may also have to do this with a diffrent OS)